# Right Way to inherit django form fields

Tags: django, forms, inheritance

`EnquiryForm` is a model form with many fields, I am not able to inherit fields of the Parent form using inheritance.

```
class EnquiryForm(models.ModelForm):
  ...
    possession = forms.ChoiceField(
      required=True,
      choices=(('', '----Select----'),) +
      models.Enquiry._meta.get_field('possession').choices,
      widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control btn btn-primary'})
    )
    ...
    # It has several other fields and clean method to manipulate user inputs and form validation


class EditForm(EnquiryForm):
    possession_month = forms.ChoiceField(
      label='Possession Month',
      required=True,
      choices=MONTHS.choices,
      widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control btn btn-primary', 'required':True})
    )
    possession_year = forms.ChoiceField(
      choices=possession_year_choices(
      datetime.now().year + 10, datetime.now().year),
      label='Possession Year',
      required=True,
      widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control btn btn-primary', 'required':True})
    )

  class Meta(EnquiryForm.Meta):
      model = models.Enquiry
      fields = EnquiryForm.Meta.fields + ('possession_month', 'possession_year', )
```

Notice here (last line), I am directly accessing `EnquiryForm.Meta.fields`. but I tried to access it by inheritance `super().fields` of the `Meta` class but no luck.

Can we inherit `fields` through `Meta` inheritance such as `super(EnquiryForm.Meta).fields`.

P.S. - Also I have to drop the field `possession` from `parent Meta.fields` in `EditForm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the get_fields method of your serializer:

```
class EditForm(EnquiryForm):
    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_fields()
        fields['possession_month'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Possession Month', required=True, choices=MONTHS.choices, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control btn btn-primary', 'required':True}))
        fields['possession_year'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=possession_year_choices(datetime.now().year + 10, datetime.now().year), label='Possession Year', required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs {'class': 'form-control btn btn-primary', 'required':True}))
        del fields['possession']
        return fields
```

But also override the Meta property of the serializer works pretty well.